# log4j configutation intelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, configuration, log4j

Trying to configure and use log4j on IntelliJ, Java project.
The new log4j version 2.9.1 comes with a bunch of different jars. Which ones should be used and where to place them?

I've copied log4j-api-2.9.1.jar, log4j-api-2.9.1-sources.jar and log4j-core-2.9.1.jar to a directory in project, and then added them to the library.

I now need to add the log4j2.xml file for the configuration, but do not know where to place it (since it also needs to be on the classpath).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Likely in the resources folder